# Magento 2: Call custom admin controller from frontend

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend

Is there a way to call custom admin controller (which prints a pdf file from sales order view page) from frontend download anchor link?

```
<a href="http://m7.local/index.php/admin/magemechanic_workorder/order/print/order_id/<?php echo $orderId ?>" download>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per **the updated question**, no, you cannot configure Magento to invoke an adminhtml controller from the frontend for security reasons. Put the code in a class, and invoke that class from both the adminthml and frontend controllers separately.

**Original answer to the original question regarding invoking one controller from another:**

You can invoke a controller just like any other code. Use Dependency Injection to get an instance on your constructor, then invoke a method on that object.

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Mod\Foo\Bar;

use Vendor\Mod\Controller\Adminhtml\Custom;

class Foobar {

    /** @var Custom */
    protected $_custom;

    public function __construct(Custom $custom)
    {
        $this->_custom = $custom;
    }


    public function foo()
    {
        $this->_custom->initPage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to call the controller on click of the anchor link. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: As per your updated question, no.

Comment: kindly can you take a look here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359058/magento2-4-2-how-to-display-only-those-payment-method-options-in-filter-in-sale