# Magento2.4.2: How to display only those payment method options in filter in sales order grid which are enabled on store front?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

**I want to display only those in this payment method filter drop down which are enabled on store front.
if i had 4 payment methos enables on store front then only four options should be shown in this payment method drop down filter in sales order grid**

[image]

**This is my approach**

> Vendor/MultiselectFilters/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Method\Options">
        <plugin name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld_Plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ActiveMethod" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

> \Vendor\Module\Plugin\ActiveMethod.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Payment\Model\Config;
use Magento\Payment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Method\Options;

class ActiveMethod
{
    /**
     * Payment Model Config
     *
     * @var Config
     */
    protected Config $paymentConfig;

    /**
     * @param Config $paymentConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $paymentConfig
    ) {
        $this->paymentConfig = $paymentConfig;
    }

    public function afterToOptionArray(
        Options $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $activeMethods[] = $this->paymentConfig->getActiveMethods();
        return [$activeMethods];

    }
}
```

**after this code i get empty drop down as in this picture**
[image]

**but when i hit debugger i get two objects in array**
[image]
**Thanks in advance. any idea how to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a 2 way, if you want to collect enabled payment for all websites, you can use following helper

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Helper/Payment.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Payment extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getPaymentMethodOptions(int $websiteId = null, bool $includeFree = true): array
    {
        $options = [];
        foreach ($this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment') as $code => $data) {
            if (!isset($data['model'], $data['title'])) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($code === 'free' && !$includeFree) {
                continue;
            }
            $title  = $data['title'];
            $active = $data['active'] ?? false;
            if ($websiteId) {
                $active = $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    sprintf('payment/%s/active', $code),
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
                    $websiteId
                );
                $title  = (string)$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    sprintf('payment/%s/title', $code),
                    ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
                    $websiteId
                );
            } else {
                foreach ($this->storeManager->getWebsites(false) as $website) {
                    $isActive = $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                        sprintf('payment/%s/active', $code),
                        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
                        $website->getId()
                    );
                    if ($isActive) {
                        $active = true;
                        $title  = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                            sprintf('payment/%s/title', $code),
                            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
                            $website->getId()
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($active) {
                $options[] = [
                    'value' => $code,
                    'title' => $title,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

or you can use `Magento\Payment\Model\Config` and format options in expected format

```
$options = [];
foreach ($this->paymentConfig->getActiveMethods() as $code => $instance) {
    $options[] = [
        'value' => $code,
        'label' => $instance->getTitle(),
    ];
}

return $options;
```

I suggest to create separate source model and overwrite it to use instead of create plugin to exists source in your case