# How to add product Image to abandoned cart API with search criteria

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to add an image to the Items in Abandoned cart API response,
I can able to add images to the rest/default/V1/carts/mine API, But unable to get in abandoned cart Items, How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to Add image to products in the Abandoned cart API response use the following approach

Abandoned cart API

`http://<rest>/rest/V1/carts/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=is_active&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][0][value]=null&searchCriteria[filter_groups][3][filters][0][condition_type]=neq`

Create extension_attributes.xml inside the etc directory and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
        <attribute code="image" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Create di.XML inside etc/webapi_rest directory and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="add_more_info" type="Adobe\CustomizeCart\Plugin\QuotePlugin" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
</config>
```

Create a plugin inside the Plugin directory

```
 <?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Adobe\CustomizeCart\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartSearchResultsInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory as ProductRepository;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;


class QuotePlugin
{

    /**
     * @var CartItemExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $cartItemExtension;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @param CartItemExtensionFactory $cartItemExtension
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(CartItemExtensionFactory $cartItemExtension, ProductRepository $productRepository, ProductImageHelper $productImageHelper)
    {
        $this->productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
        $this->cartItemExtension = $cartItemExtension;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Add attribute values
     *
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $subject ,
     * @param   $quote
     * @return  $quoteData
     */
    public function afterGet(CartRepositoryInterface $subject, $quote)
    {
        $quoteData = $this->setAttributeValue($quote);
        return $quoteData;
    }

    /**
     * set value of attributes
     *
     * @param   $product ,
     * @return  $extensionAttributes
     */
    private function setAttributeValue($quote)
    {
        $data = [];
        if ($quote->getItemsCount()) {
            foreach ($quote->getItems() as $item) {
                $data = [];
                $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes();
                if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
                    $extensionAttributes = $this->cartItemExtension->create();
                }
                $product = $this->productRepository->create()->get($item->getSku());
                $imageurl = $this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getThumbnail())->getUrl();

                $extensionAttributes->setImage($imageurl);

                $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            }
        }

        return $quote;
    }

    public function afterGetList(CartRepositoryInterface $subject, CartSearchResultsInterface $searchResults)
    {
        foreach ($searchResults->getItems() as $entity) {
            foreach ($entity->getItems() as $singleItem) {
                $extensionAttributes = $singleItem->getExtensionAttributes();
                if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
                    $extensionAttributes = $this->cartItemExtension->create();
                }
                $product = $this->productRepository->create()->get($singleItem->getSku());
                $imageurl = $this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getThumbnail())->getUrl();
                $extensionAttributes->setImage($imageurl);
                $singleItem->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            }
        }
        return $searchResults;
    }

    /**
     * Add attribute values
     *
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $subject ,
     * @param   $quote
     * @return  $quoteData
     */
    public function afterGetActiveForCustomer(CartRepositoryInterface $subject, $quote)
    {
        $quoteData = $this->setAttributeValue($quote);
        return $quoteData;
    }

}
```

After this, you will get a response like this

```
 {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "created_at": "2022-08-09 07:51:39",
            "updated_at": "2022-08-19 13:40:35",
            "is_active": true,
            "is_virtual": false,
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": 36,
                    "sku": "24-MB01",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
                    "price": 34,
                    "product_type": "simple",
                    "quote_id": "10",
                    "extension_attributes": {
                        "image": "http://commerce.test/media/catalog/product\\cache\\1b586fea9684f361adf9ddaf06adedaf\\/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "item_id": 37,
                    "sku": "24-MB04",
                    "qty": 1,
                    "name": "Strive Shoulder Pack",
                    "price": 32,
                    "product_type": "simple",
                    "quote_id": "10",
                    "extension_attributes": {
                        "image": "http://commerce.test/media/catalog/product\\cache\\1b586fea9684f361adf9ddaf06adedaf\\/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "items_count": 2,
            "items_qty": 2,
            "customer": {
                "id": 2,
                "group_id": 1,
                "dob": "1973-12-15",
                "email": "roni_cost@example.com",
                "firstname": "Veronica",
                "lastname": "Costello",
                "gender": 2,
                "store_id": 1,
                "website_id": 1,
              }
               
    ]
    "total_count": 1
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks,
but kindly can you take a look here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359058/magento2-4-2-how-to-display-only-those-payment-method-options-in-filter-in-sale